# how to change the div width according to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `table` which is editable. I want to change the `div` width when the `td` content changes. I think my jQuery code is not working. How can I solve this problem?

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
number = document.getElementById('number');
form.onchange = function() {
  var variable = number.value;
  var unit = "px";
  var z = variable + unit;
  $("#check").css("width", z);
};
```

```css
#check {
  background-color: red;
  height: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="number" type="number" min="1" name="number">
      </form>
      <div id="check"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it is working you can see in the snippet

Comment: I think you mean `number.onchange`, not `form.onchange`. If you fix that it works fine.

Comment: i cant see any problems in the code please elaborate where you are stuck

Comment: It works, but only when you click outside, onchange in this case is similar to onblur. If you want to see variation every carachter you may use onKeyUp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery with `keyup` and `change`

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
number = document.getElementById('number');
$("#number").on("keyup change",function() {
  var variable = number.value;
  var unit = "px";
  var z = variable + unit;
  $("#check").css("width", z);
});
```

```css
#check {
  background-color: red;
  height: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="number" type="number" min="1" name="number">
      </form>
      <div id="check"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```